# Circuit SDK error on method circuit.logon

Tags: circuit-sdk

I'm trying to move my bot for Circuit to production. My app for it uploaded on Azure Web App Service. When I test bot on sandbox it works great. But if I change only config (client_id, client_secred and domain) and restart app it falls on method **circuit.logon** with this error message:

```
Error on ciruit.logon. The Application null  is not enabled for scope ::=[CALL_RECORDING]
```

If I specify a scope on creating circuit client like that:

```
scope: 'READ_USER_PROFILE'
```

or any other scope it changes to:

```
Error on ciruit.logon. The Application null  is not enabled for scope ::=[READ_USER_PROFILE]
```

The Application **null** bothers me. And I tried all scopes due to last part of error but it won't work. What could cause this error?

Comment: This should work fine, especially since the same code worked on the sandbox. If you don't specify a scope in the Circuit.Client constructor, then the SDK asked for all scopes. In that case the app should be registered with all scopes. But if you just request READ_USER_PROFILE for example in the Circuit.Client constructor, then the app only need at least that scope set in its registration. The 'application null' is not a problem. The only thing I can think of is that the bot registration does not have any scopes defined. Try to change the registration scopes for your bot and save if again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Roger said :

> This should work fine, especially since the same code worked on the
>   sandbox. If you don't specify a scope in the Circuit.Client
>   constructor, then the SDK asked for all scopes. In that case the app
>   should be registered with all scopes. But if you just request
>   READ_USER_PROFILE for example in the Circuit.Client constructor, then
>   the app only need at least that scope set in its registration. The
>   'application null' is not a problem. The only thing I can think of is
>   that the bot registration does not have any scopes defined. Try to
>   change the registration scopes for your bot and save if again

I copy his comment as "an answer" so that the Andrey has the opportunity to select a "good answer" for his request.